# delete code in trigger throwing up errors oracle

Tags: oracle

i don't know how the code throws up errors. it compiles correctly but when it used it throws up an error.

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_APPLICATIONS
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE OF APP_ID, STATUS_ID
ON APPLICATIONS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

:new.APP_ID := SEQ_APP_ID.nextval;
:new.APP_DATE := SYSDATE;

IF UPDATING AND ( :NEW.STATUS_ID = 2 OR :NEW.STATUS_ID = 5 OR :NEW.STATUS_ID = 7 OR :NEW.STATUS_ID = 8 )
THEN
   INSERT INTO APP_HISTORY (SRN, STATUS_ID, APP_DATE)
   VALUES (:OLD.SRN, :OLD.STATUS_ID, :OLD.APP_DATE);       

       DELETE FROM APPLICATIONS    WHERE :NEW.STATUS_ID = 2;
       DELETE FROM APPLICATIONS    WHERE :NEW.STATUS_ID = 5;
       DELETE FROM APPLICATIONS    WHERE :NEW.STATUS_ID = 7;
       DELETE FROM APPLICATIONS    WHERE :NEW.STATUS_ID = 8;

END IF;

END;
```

this is the error message

```
error ORA-04091: table APEX514.APPLICATIONS is mutating, 
trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at "APEX514.TRG_APPLICATIONS", 
line 14 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'APEX514.TRG_APPLICATIONS'
```

Comment: what is the error code exactly?

Comment: (this was the full error message error) error ORA-04091: table APEX514.APPLICATIONS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at "APEX514.TRG_APPLICATIONS", line 14 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'APEX514.TRG_APPLICATIONS'

Comment: Please edit the error message into your question using the `edit` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of a mutating table error is the misuse of triggers. Here is a typical example:
1.you insert a row in table A

2.a trigger on table A (for each row) executes a query on table A, for example to compute a summary column

3.Oracle throws an ORA-04091: table A is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Source for further reading. [http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/what-are-the-causes-and-solutions-for-mutating-table-errors](http://Mutating%20Table)

Comment: A mutating table occurs when a statement causes a trigger to fire(UPDATE or INSERT in your case)  and that trigger(DELETE) references the table that caused the trigger. You have two DMLs in one trigger that references the same table which causes an inconsistent state of data.

Comment: the bottom line is that you should move the code to functions / procedures and not store it in a trigger... There is a solution to use compound trigger instead of 'regular' one but I would personally advise not to if possible :) here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32473980/oracle-trigger-to-update-all-the-rows-of-table-based-on-the-data-of-updating-col/32474225#32474225